# Regular expression to split the hostname(FQDN) to obtain the first part in python string

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
device_name = "english-in-en-2g.pr.xyz.com"

if '.' in device_name:
     print('yes')
else:
     print('no')


Out[24]: yes

device_name.split(r'\.[a-zA-Z]',1)[0]

Out[25]: 'english-in-en-2g.pr.xyz.com'
```

Need the following output:

```
"english-in-en-2g"
```

splited with `.`(dot)

I also have IP address to ignore that why I tried the following regular expression `device_name.split(r'\.[a-zA-Z]',1)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to check if `device_name` is an IP address and ignore splitting if it is. Otherwise, split fqdn to get the first part.

IP address can be verified using the `ipaddress` module.

```
import ipaddress
def is_ip_address(addr):
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(addr)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

The `device_name` can then be compared for IP address and can be split by `'.'` if it is not.

```
if not is_ip_address(device_name):
    first_part = device_name.split(".")[0]
```

Hope this helps.